# Magento fast search API

Tags: catalogsearch, search

I am not sure if this question can be asked here. Though i am am asking after doing some research on google.

**Basically i want a search like Ebay, Amazon or Flipkart. Which should be faster and easy to maintain(Might be if possible).**

**I have around 10000k products on the store. And using sphinx search at this moment. But its not very good in terms of speed or maintenance.**

**I need to reindex for around 8-10 hours after adding products on the store and search is also not fast.**

Can you guys please suggest how i can get a better search which will be lightening fast for products, categories etc and easy to maintain.

Again this question should not belong here may be but i think as my site is based on Magento then you guys are the best ones to ask.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest a solution we use : Algolia https://www.algolia.com/
There is a module for this https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento
You can also see it in action in one of our customer : http://www.whisky.fr/catalogsearch/result/?q= the search is powered by Algolia

Comment: seems is very fast..but do you have any idea how it will work on around 1000k or more products?

Comment: I don't have benchmark in mind but you can ask us there are very reactive

Comment: Here you can find some benchmarks / informations from 2013 : https://blog.algolia.com/full-text-search-in-your-database-algolia-versus-elasticsearch/